# Stop formulas that reference a worksheet from updating until I'm done running my macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that automatically loops through files in a folder, and writes several contents of each file onto a single master file. There are multiple worksheets that reference this main data dump worksheet through formulas. There are thousands of formulas and this is slowing down the macro greatly and causes it to crash almost everytime. Is there a way I can pause the formulas in all other sheets till my macro is done running? When I try running the macro without references, it works like a charm.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim Sht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    MyFolder = "C:\Users\durs\Desktop\Filtered\"

    Set Sht = Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Sheets("Log")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = Sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'loop through directory file and print names
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        'If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "csv" Then
            'print file name

            Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & objFile.Name
            Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

            With WB
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
                    Sht.Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name

                    With ws

                        Sht.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Mid(.Range("A16").Value, 13, 11)
                        Sht.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = Right(.Range("A13").Value, 1)
                        Sht.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Right(.Range("A14").Value, 2)

                    End With
                    i = i + 1
                Next ws
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        'End If
    Next objFile

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Although, the above works well, thanks to all you guys on this site, I need to find a way to pause other worksheets from updating while the macro runs on this. Thanks

Comment: Add `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning of the code. Your can turn it back on with `xlCalculationAutomatic`. It turns off (and on) the automatic calculation if a cell is altered.

Comment: In addition to above, `Application.EnableEvents = False` might also speed up your process.

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys